# Prevent re-render using React.memo and React.useCallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

For learning purpose,

I am trying prevent re-render on `<InputWithLable />` component whenever i Dismiss a search result (see deploy in [Full code](https://codesandbox.io/s/input-with-label-rerender-p0thx))

I have use `React.memo` but it still re-render. So I think maybe its `props` is the culprit. I use `React.useCallback` to `handleSearch` prop, but it doesn't work.

[Full code](https://codesandbox.io/s/input-with-label-rerender-p0thx)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React from 'react';

const API_ENDPOINT = 'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=';

const useSemiPersistentState = (key, initialState) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
    localStorage.getItem(key) || initialState
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
  }, [value, key]);

  return [value, setValue];
};

function storiesReducer(prevState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET":
      return { ...prevState, data: action.data, isLoading: false, isError: false };
    case "REMOVE":
      return {
        ...prevState,
        data: prevState.data.filter(
          story => action.data.objectID !== story.objectID
        )
      }
    case "ERROR":
      return { ...prevState, isLoading: false, isError: true };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useSemiPersistentState(
    'search',
    'Google'
  );

  const [stories, dispatchStories] = React.useReducer(storiesReducer, { data: [], isLoading: true, isError: false });
  const [url, setUrl] = React.useState("");
  const handleFetchStories = React.useCallback(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        dispatchStories({ type: "SET", data: result.hits })
      })
      .catch(err => dispatchStories({ type: "ERROR", data: err }))
  }, [url])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    handleFetchStories();
  }, [handleFetchStories])


  const handleRemoveStory = React.useCallback(
    (item) => {
      dispatchStories({ type: "REMOVE", data: item });
    },
    [], // chi render 1 lan vi props khong thay doi
  )

  const handleSearch = React.useCallback(
    (e) => {
      setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
    },
    [],
  )

  // Chuc nang filter la cua server (vd: database)
  // const searchedStories = stories.data ? stories.data.filter(story =>
  //   story.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
  // ) : null; // nghich cai nay!

  console.log('App render');

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My Hacker Stories</h1>

      <InputWithLabel
        id="search"
        value={searchTerm}
        isFocused
        onInputChange={handleSearch}
      >
        <strong>Search:</strong>
      </InputWithLabel>

      <button onClick={() => setUrl(API_ENDPOINT + searchTerm)}>Search!</button>

      <hr />

      {stories.isError && <h4>ERROR!</h4>}

      {stories.isLoading ? <i>Loading...</i>
        : <List list={stories.data} onRemoveItem={handleRemoveStory} />}
    </div>
  );
};

const InputWithLabel = React.memo(
  ({
    id,
    value,
    type = 'text',
    onInputChange,
    isFocused,
    children,
  }) => {
    const inputRef = React.useRef();

    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (isFocused) {
        inputRef.current.focus();
      }
    }, [isFocused]);

    console.log('Search render')

    return (
      <>
        <label htmlFor={id}>{children}</label>
        &nbsp;
        <input
          ref={inputRef}
          id={id}
          type={type}
          value={value}
          onChange={onInputChange}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
);

// Prevent default React render mechanism: Parent rerender -> Child rerender
const List = React.memo(
  ({ list, onRemoveItem }) =>
    console.log('List render') || list.map(item => (
      <Item
        key={item.objectID}
        item={item}
        onRemoveItem={onRemoveItem}
      />
    ))
);

const Item = ({ item, onRemoveItem }) => (
  <div>
    <span>
      <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
    </span>
    <span>{item.author}</span>
    <span>{item.num_comments}</span>
    <span>{item.points}</span>
    <span>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => onRemoveItem(item)}>
        Dismiss
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to prevent a rerender there? Of course it needs to rerender when the search term changes. Also, just logging renders and seeing multiple of them in the console isn't necessarily indicative of a performance issue.

Comment: Start by figuring out what prop is causing the rerender

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). What is `searchTerm`? It appears out of nowhere in the code. Presumably it's state in `App`?

Comment: I don't see anything *else* in the parent component (`App`) but things that would, quite correctly, need to re-render `InputWithLabel`. What change are you making that you think shouldn't re-render it?

Comment: I agree with @AKX , why do you even need to memoize the component? It's just an input field with label, that wont cause you any performance issues.

Comment: @TJCrowder I just edit my post. Though I had added codesanbox link

Comment: @AKX  just edit my post to clearly said my purpose is for learning

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but this will save you a lot of effort in the future.

I would recommend you to use [`why-did-you-render`][1] package to automatically detect unnecessary rendering. It also provided some directions on why might this happen and how to solve it.


  [1]: https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be looking at how many times a component's render function gets called; React is free to call it as many times as it likes (and indeed, in strict mode, it calls them twice to help you not make mistakes).

But to answer your question (with the actual code that uses `children`):

```
<InputWithLabel>
   <strong>Search:</strong>
</InputWithLabel>
```

compiles down to

```
React.createElement(InputWithLabel, null,
    React.createElement("strong", null, "Search:"))
```

the identity of the `children` prop (the `<strong />` element) changes for each render of the parent component since `React.createElement()` returns new objects for each invocation. Since that identity changes, `React.memo` does nothing.

If you wanted to (but **please don't**), you could do

```
const child = React.useMemo(() => <strong>Search:</strong>);
// ...
<InputWithLabel>{child}</InputWithLabel>
```

but doing that for all of your markup leads to nigh-unreadable code.

Comment: For learning purpose only. Thanks. Though, I just remove `children` and instead put `<strong>Search:</strong>` inside `<label></label>` in `<InputWithLabel \>`. But it still re-render, why?